# How to make database calls through an API in Nuxt/Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've been introducing myself to Vue/Nuxt and have begun experimenting with API's. I'm trying to move the logic in my NuxtServerInit function to an API.

```
  nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    return context.app.$axios
      .$get(process.env.baseUrl + "/posts.json")
      .then(data => {
        const postsArray = [];
        for (const key in data) {
          postsArray.push({ ...data[key], id: key });
        }
        vuexContext.commit("modules/modPost/setPosts", postsArray);
      })
      .catch(e => context.error(e));
  }
```

The problem I'm having is accessing the context in order to make the DB call.

The API looking something like this:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const glob = require("glob");
const router = Router();

router.post("/carousel/posts", async function(req, res) {
  return context.app.axios
    .get(process.env.baseUrl + "/posts.json")
    .then(data => {
      const postsArray = [];
      for (const key in data) {
        postsArray.push({ ...data[key], id: key });
      }
      vuexContext.commit("modules/modPost/setPosts", postsArray);
    })
    .catch(e => context.error(e));
});

module.exports = router;
```

I tried making a POST request thinking I could send the context as a parameter but I it feels wrong...

```
   async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    const ps = await $axios.$post(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/carousel/posts", {context});
    return { ps };
  }
```

I should note here, that I am fairly sure that in the API, the line is wrong:

```
vuexContext.commit("modules/modPost/setPosts", postsArray);
```

I believe it would generally execute in the asyncdata, on what is returned by the API.

So to summarize, I have two questions.

1. Is what I am trying to accomplish reasonable?
2. What am I missing to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see here bad workflow. I suggest you to analyze how the communication between the Express and Nuxt is going. Take a look at this [auth example](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-routes)

*vuexContext.commit* is the vuex method, and you use it on the server side (express), which is a mistake. In simplified terms, communication could look like:

1. client side request to server/call vuex action
2. server (express in your case) make something with data CRUD, and return response
3. vuex action receives a response from the server, commit changes
4. vue/nuxt render changes

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I figured it out within ten minutes of posting. Ugh.

For number 2, added this to the API:

```
router.post("/carousel/posts", async function(req, res) {
  const darts = await axios.get(process.env.baseUrl + "/posts.json");
  return res.json(darts.data);
});
```

And asyncData:

```
 async asyncData({ $axios, store }) {
    //console.log($axios);
    const ps = await $axios.$post(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/carousel/posts"
    );

    const postsArray = [];
    for (const key in ps) {
      postsArray.push({ ...ps[key], id: key });
    }
    store.commit("modules/modPost/setPosts", postsArray);
    return { ps };
  }
```

Also still interested in reasonability / best practices / opinions...